# Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) out of support

Tags: 12.04, kernel, hardware-enablement-stack

From yesterday my update manager gives me this message:

> Your current Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is going out of support
>   on 07/08/2014.  After this date security updates for critical parts (kernel
>   and graphics stack) of your system will no longer be available.
>
> For more information, please see: http://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL

But when I try to upgrade the HWE with the command suggested by `hwe-support-status --verbose` that is

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty linux-image-generic-lts-trusty
```

I get dependency errors:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty : Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-lts-trusty : Recommends: xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-trusty but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: x11-xserver-utils-lts-trusty but it is not going to be installed
                           Conflicts: libglapi-mesa:i386 (>= 0~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I solve this?

I'm running `Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS` 64 bit with kernel `3.5.0-53-generic`.

Comment: There is [a bug discussing this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1328264) but as yet I haven't found a solution.

Comment: I don't have enough points to comment so I must answer.
Dogsbody's answer didn't work for me.
ECII's one did (I tried the amd64 version).

Comment: Just an FYI: I have a [similar but slightly different issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/496199/hwe-support-status-does-not-tell-me-how-to-upgrade-to-12-04-5) where there are no packages recommended.

Comment: Please take note that different users seem to be reporting different things on HWE upgrade problems/solutions. See [hwe-support-status does not tell me how to upgrade to 12.04.5](http://askubuntu.com/questions/496199/hwe-support-status-does-not-tell-me-how-to-upgrade-to-12-04-5), [Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) out of support](http://askubuntu.com/questions/493541/hardware-enablement-stack-hwe-out-of-support), [bug #1341324](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1341324), and [bug #1341320](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1341320).

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, this is what worked for me

Command:

**For amd64:**

```
sudo apt-get install -V libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty x11-xserver-utils-lts-trusty libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty:i386 libgles2-mesa-lts-trusty libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty mesa-vdpau-drivers-lts-trusty
```

**For i386:**

```
sudo apt-get install -V libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty x11-xserver-utils-lts-trusty mesa-vdpau-drivers-lts-trusty libgles2-mesa-lts-trusty libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty
```

Comment: There is an extra space in the name of package `xserver-xorg-lts-trusty` at the end of first line of `amd64``

Comment: I don't know why this was voted down, it fixed the problem for me...

Comment: Using your command (64bit version) broke other packages dependencies for me.. I solve by fresh installing the `14.04 LTS`

Answer (score 6):

Manually installing `xserver-xorg-lts-precise` first will make sure you have all the dependencies you need.  Then install the packages defined by `hwe-support-status`.

For you this means running the two commands...

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-precise
hwe-support-status --verbose
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty linux-image-generic-lts-trusty
```

This issue is discussed in [bug #1328264](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1328264) I just hadn't read it properly :-)

Comment: Installing `xserver-xorg-lts-trusty` installed the other packages for me.

Comment: Yes, different systems will have different packages.  They should all resolve dependencies correctly though :-/