# hwe-support-status does not tell me how to upgrade to 12.04.5

Tags: 12.04, server, upgrade, hardware-enablement-stack

According to [1204_HWE-EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL#What_to_do_if_I.27m_affected.3F), there should be an option to upgrade to 12.04.5 HWE, however, I do not receive any such instructions from `hwe-support-status`.

```
# uname -r
3.11.0-24-generic
# hwe-support-status --verbose

Your current Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is going out of support
on 08/07/2014.  After this date security updates for critical parts (kernel
and graphics stack) of your system will no longer be available.

For more information, please see:
http://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL

To upgrade to a supported (or longer supported) configuration:

* Upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by running:
sudo do-release-upgrade -p

OR

* Install a newer HWE version by running:
sudo apt-get install

and reboot your system.
```

On a different server, I get the same message as above, except it actually states the packages to install:

```
* Install a newer HWE version by running:
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty linux-image-generic-lts-trusty
```

I'm not sure if this is how to update all HWEs or if the packages change based on different hardware.

This appears to be the same as [Bug #1341320](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1341320).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only because no one else was able to answer this question am I posting a "fix" that worked for me.

I used the same commands to update this server as I did with other servers.

```
# apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty linux-image-generic-lts-trusty
```

After reboot, everything appears to work fine.

```
# hwe-support-status
Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2017.
```

Nothing unusual being reported in the logs.

Comment: Worked like a charm! From `$ uname -r > 3.5.0-18-generic`
`$ lsb_release -a > Description: Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS` to `$ uname -r > 3.13.0-45-generic` `$ hwe-support-status > Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2017.`

Answer (score 1):

According to this source:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

It seems to me that this is the way to do it:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty
```

Not sure if all the packages are needed, but I think I will install all of them just in case.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution as [others are reporting problems](http://askubuntu.com/questions/493541/hardware-enablement-stack-hwe-out-of-support). Also see my edit to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the specific flavor of Ubuntu that you are running, it may be correct that you get a blank command for an update.  The 12.04.5 point release was not originally planned.  Please [check the release announcement](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2014-August/000189.html) to verify if you are in fact using a flavor that should be receiving the update.  Your reference to a Mythbuntu-related bug in the question notwithstanding the server tag does make it necessary to double-check if you are using a flavor eligible for 12.04.5.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04.5, originally installed via Ubuntu 12.04.4 iso download from the Ubuntu website. Given that there are other bugs reported by the user Frankster on that user's same system that were HWE related and affecting me, I don't think the fact that it is Mythbuntu makes any difference.