# "Your current Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is going out of support"

Tags: apt, kernel, release-management, hardware-enablement-stack

My ubuntu system now says;

> Your current Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is going out of support
>   on 07. aug. 2014.  After this date security updates for critical parts
>   (kernel and graphics stack) of your system will no longer be
>   available.

and suggests to fix it by doing:

> sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty
>   linux-image-generic-lts-trusty

However, on this website:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

they state the following:

> Those running virtual or cloud images should not need these newer
>   enablement stacks and are thus recommended to remain on the original
>   Precise stack

and I do run on a VM. So I'm a little confused.
Should I update the HWE with apt-get or not? It seems to me that I really should, as it seems I might miss important security updates if I don't...but the website also seems to state that I don't need to do so if I run virtual?

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/500508/how-does-lts-combine-with-hwe-out-of-support

Comment: Possibly. Still reading... but so far I haven't seen anything specific to the VM scenario

Comment: Alright, I think I got it now. The LTSEnablementStack article is suggesting that I use 12.0.4 prior to v3,4 or 5? I notice I already got 12.0.4.4 LTS, so I'm guessing that means I really do should update, as I'm already in violation of the suggestion of not enabling the LTSENablementStack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04.4 it means you are using the Saucy kernel, since Ubuntu Saucy ended support two days ago that means your current kernel will drop security support and you will not recieve security updates so you need to do as suggested by the system update.