# Intel® HD Graphics 530 compatibility with 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I think my fresh Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64 does not work properly with my Intel® HD Graphics 530, because I can't rotate the Display. Is there a way to get to get this graphics chip running? I think there are no official drivers from intel for it...

```
root@test:~# xrandr -o right
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  2 (RRSetScreenConfig)
  Serial number of failed request:  14
  Current serial number in output stream:  14
```

Greetz form Austria, 
Florian Miesenberger

Comment: for a fresh install I would recommend going with something newer than 12.04, what about 14.04 or 16.04 as these are also LTS releases?

Comment: I really would like to do, but our applications are only running on 12.04 for now.  Are there any suggestions?

Comment: following two wiki pages might be helpful: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL  - by the way it might be necessary to port this software to a newer version of ubuntu as 12.04-support will end in April 2017

Comment: sorry this post might be of better help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/493541/hardware-enablement-stack-hwe-out-of-support

Comment: Trawling though Intel's website, it seems they don't support kernels older than 4.4 for Skylake IGPs.

Comment: OK. Thank you for answers! I will take a look at the LTSEnablementStack-thing. @PatrickNegus: Does this mean that I only have to upgrade the kernel and then can I install the current drivers?

Comment: Is there a way to upgrade the kernel to 4.4 oder higher in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Comment: OK. It seem's that there is no easy and time-saving way to get these new Intel grapgics chips working in old Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. We dealt with the problem by buying a Radeon R5 340X. AMD/ATI is also maintaining their drivers for older linux systems. Big THANKS to all here!